# program resets after ISR for TIMER 2 on pic24F

Tags: pic, timer, reset, isr

I am trying to configure the timer2, but every time that an interrupt occurs, the microcontroller goes to the ISR and then starts the main() function again.
This are the functions:

```
int main(void)
{

   //Set up I/O Port
   AD1PCFGL  =  0xFFFF;  //set to all digital I/O
   TRISB    =   0x0000;  //configure all PortB as input, RB9 as output
   //Main Program Loop, Loop forever
   Timer2Init();

   while(1)
    {
      //LATBbits.LATB1=0;//process data
    };

   return(0);
}
```

I have the timer2 functions in a timers.c file

```
void Timer2Init(void)
{
   TMR2 = 0;// clear the timer
   T2CONbits.T32=0;  //
   T2CONbits.TCKPS = 0b00; // prescaler = 256
   T2CONbits.TGATE = 0; //0 = Gated time accumulation disabled
   T2CONbits.TCS = 0; //Internal clock (FOSC/2)
   PR2 = 0x50; // preset
   IEC0bits.T2IE = 1;
   IPC1bits.IC2IP = 0b111;//set interrupt priority
   T2CONbits.TON =1;
   IFS0bits.T2IF = 0;
}


void __attribute__((interrupt, no_auto_psv)) _T2Interrupt(void)
{

    LATBbits.LATB9 = ~LATBbits.LATB9;   //Toggle output to LED
    IFS0bits.T2IF = 0; //_T1IF = 0;
    return;
}
```

Comment: How have you determined that it's resetting?

Comment: Is your timer running too fast for the ISR? "   T2CONbits.TCKPS = 0b00; // prescaler = 256" - you're lying there...

Comment: post your conf.bits. If you have WDT enabled it will reset the micro no matter what unbless you clear it manually. Also, define an ISR for NMI, like address error, math, etc., and put while(1) into the body of the ISR so that when you hit the NMI condition the PC will point to it instead of resetting the micro.

Comment: Why do you have a "return;" at the end of your ISR? You may be confusing the compiler into producing the incorrect ISR exit code...